# Audio play for attraction

Tags: voice-over, sound-editing

Hello everyone,

After looking around a bit I haven't seen something that really answers my question.  Our company has been asked to write, cast, record and edit an audio play for a tourist attraction.  Basically the audio will play for 15 minutes as they walk through and experience the visuals.  Having never worked a gig like this (we usually just do video) I've heard so many different opinions on what we should charge that I'm confused.  What do you think this project is worth?  There is a cost to go through this attraction, so it is a for profit enterprise.  More than willing to answer any other detail questions.  Thank you!

Comment: Royalties? If you can negotiate it that is.

Answer (score 1):

> Our company has been asked to write, cast, record and edit an audio play for a tourist attraction.

Do you have a hourly price for audio recording/editing? I think this is the easiest part of the equation. Just calculate the hours needed and leave room for changes the client will request or just bill them per hour.

I assume that your client will want to include the voiceover costs in the deal? You have to be very careful here about the price. Depending on how many speakers and what usage rights you buy, you can end up reaching for your own purse if you don't calculate everything carefully. You can use a voiceover agency or do the casting yourself. Be sure to check the rights of the voiceovers, so you don't get any surprises. Make sure it is a buyout and you don't have to pay any recurring yearly costs.

It will be easier to you if you have the budget to use an agency, as they have already recorded the talent for you. You don't lose any time fixing the schedules, only to hear the client doesn't approve your choices.

Writing it is the hardest to estimate. Will you be provided with any material or do you have to write everything from scratch? 15min of voiceover if a lot to write.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a producer at a sound recording studio called We Love Jam in Sydney, Australia and we do this type of work all the time. I have to agree, hourly rate is the way to go and work back from there. Plus include the incidentals like WAV Masters, Archives, Stationery, Catering, etc. Whatever is potential expenditure. Feel free to comment if you need further clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I made one slight alteration.  Since the idea of the Q/A site is to make sure that we have complete answers, it is really best if the user comment on your answer if they need further clarification and you can then edit your answer to include the detail so everyone can benefit from the additional detail.  You should get notified when someone comments.  You can also publish your e-mail or website in your profile if you want, that way you don't have to give it out on every answer.